# Слетает apache, Удаляется порт 80 в ports.conf. Автоматически запускается nginx

Tags: linux, django, сервер, nginx, apache2

Слетает apache, Удаляется порт 80 в ports.conf. Автоматически запускается nginx,
который мне не нужен. Происходит это где-то 1-2 раза в день. 
Приходится заново писать в ports.conf apach'a `Listen 80` и останавливать nginx
командой `systemctl stop nginx`

Только после этого возможен доступ к сайту. А в момент когда он слетает при заходе на сайт ошибка 404 и пишет что сервер Nginx.

Так было не всегда. где-то 2-3 недели. До этого 2-3 месяца все было в порядке.

Что это может быть?

Comment: Так удали нгинкс, раз не нужен

Comment: Удалить всегда успеется, но надо же понять в чем причина прежде чем применять радикальное решение.Может это решается одной командой. Так чтобы nginx и apache не конфликтовали.

Comment: если удаляется строчка - то её ктото удаляет. У Вас стоит какая-нибудь панель управления?

Comment: nginx можно удалить из запуска `systemctl mask nginx` или настроить на другой порт. но это не решит проблему с апачем и удалением строки.

Comment: Да. На nginx стоит fastpanel. Но я ей не пользуюсь.

Попробую команду `systemctl mask nginx`.

Как будто конфиги  apache восстанавливаются в исходное состояние.

Comment: так панель и бъет настройки твои. найди где у неё автозапуск и тоже выключи до лучших времен

Comment: Как найти? Где посмотреть?

Comment: У меня чтобы был доступ к сайту надо конфиги apache ставить на 80 порт. Ставишь другой в шапке VirtualHost- сайт недоступен. Может есть способ как то поставить другой порт на apache чтобы он не конфликтовал?

Comment: надо смотреть в сторону fastpanel

Comment: Раньше такого не было. Все было в порядке. Может ли это быть вирус?

Comment: вирусы не портят систему, практически никогда. займись панелью или удали её

Answer (score 0):

Просматривая логи nginx, apache и fastpanel, выяснилось, что конфиг апача(и не только) действительно бьет панель fastpanel, производя автообновление и переписывая все файлы. Написал в поддержку хостинга, подтвердили, что да, так и есть. Так как сервер заказан именно с панелью через которую проводится вся настройка, вручную настраивать я не могу. Говорят надо было брать сервер без панели. Принесли свои извинения, что мне пришлось столкнуться с этим.
Также говорят что отключить нельзя, в связи с соображениями безопасности.

[eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16574/eri) спасибо за отзыв